# Images links not updated after pushing site from staging to primary domain

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have pushed site from staging http://copy.fbmgusa.com to primary domain https://fbmgusa.com but images links are not updated.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried to update urls using plugins i. e **"better search and replace"** and **"search and replace"**. Also used sql query in database to update images links but only home page images links are updated. All other pages images links are not updated and still referring to old staging link.

Also trie to re-upload images in elementor but no success.

I need your SUGGESTIONS how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementor have built-in tool for this:
Go to **Elementor > Tools** then open **Replace URL** tab, input http://copy.fbmgusa.com  in the **Old URL** and  https://fbmgusa.com in **New URL** fields then click **Replace URl** button (please below image for more detail).

Please remenber to clear all the cache after this process.

[image]